# Building a debug APK

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm having trouble with building a debuggable apk. I'm using Android Studio 0.5.4/0.5.5 and Gradle 1.11 Gradle plugin 0.9.+ and somehow the debug apk doesn't show any logcat messages with the package name anymore. I tried many different things uninstall everything Android studio/AndroidSDK. and clean installing it again, also deleted all home folder .gradle .androidstudiopreview and nothing helped. When I created a new project in android studio and follow the wizard for creating an activity everything seems fine the app is debuggable and shows normal logging output in logcat. Also when I want to selected the process for debug, Android Studio can't find it as a debuggable process. Anyone know how to fix this or what is wrong in my build.gradle file

the output from log messages is like this now:

```
04-15 14:09:11.066  21202-21202/? D/Tag﹕ test tag and debug messages
04-15 14:09:11.066  21202-21202/? I/Tag﹕ test tag and info messages
04-15 14:09:11.066  21202-21202/? W/Tag﹕ test tag and warn messages
04-15 14:09:11.066  21202-21202/? E/Tag﹕ test tag and error messages
04-15 14:09:11.076  21202-21202/? D/Tag﹕ is debuggable: true
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

def gitSha() {
    return 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
}

def buildTime() {
    return new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
}

def isTravis = "true".equals(System.getenv("TRAVIS"))
def preDexEnabled = "true".equals(System.getProperty("pre-dex", "true"))

android {
    final GITSHA = "${gitSha()}";
    final BUILD_TIME = "${buildTime()}";
    final YOUTUBE_DEV_API = "AIzaSyD0kNRnV_Il6bYx5ekWUzPWNt9XDQIPxvg"

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    dexOptions {
        // Skip pre-dexing when running on Travis CI or when disabled via -Dpre-dex=false.
        preDexLibraries = preDexEnabled && !isTravis
    }

    defaultConfig {
        packageName "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(VERSION_CODE)
        versionName VERSION_NAME
        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${GITSHA}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${BUILD_TIME}\""
        testPackageName "com.whosampled.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        testFunctionalTest true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("../test.keystore")
            storePassword "#2U3aD+2ASwayEwa"
            keyAlias "debug"
            keyPassword "gu*W5cUkUM-&5bre"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable false
            jniDebugBuild false
            zipAlign true
            buildConfigField "String", "YOUTUBE_API", "\"${YOUTUBE_DEV_API}\""
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            debuggable true
            jniDebugBuild true
            runProguard false
            zipAlign false
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-" + GITSHA + "-debug"
            buildConfigField "String", "YOUTUBE_API", "\"${YOUTUBE_DEV_API}\""
        }

        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            println "*********" + variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getBuildType().isDebuggable() + "**********";
        }

        if (false) {
            // change apk off build variant.
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                println "*********" + variant.description + "**********";
                def variants = variant.baseName.split("-");
                variant.buildType
                def apkName = "whosampled-";
                apkName += variants[0];

                apkName += "-v" + android.defaultConfig.versionName;

                apkName += "-" + GITSHA;
                if (!variant.zipAlign) {
                    apkName += "-unaligned";
                }

                // if created by build server or something
                if (false && variant.buildType.name == "release") {
                    apkName += "-RELEASE.apk";
                } else if (false && variant.buildType.name == "debug") {
                    apkName += "-SNAPSHOT.apk";
                } else {
                    apkName += ".apk";
                }
                println "*********" + "$project.buildDir/apk/" + apkName + "**********";
                variant.outputFile = file("$project.buildDir/apk/" + apkName)
            }
        }

    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/' }
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.5.3'
    compile 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
    compile 'com.pixplicity:font.text.utils.library:1.2@aar'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Gradle. the log output shows a pid and ddms gives a pid->app package mapping so the display of the log is studio uses the map to display the app package.

Comment: so what could be causing this? it was working normally and the all at once i couldn't debug anymore and I don't know what i did wrong.